# What is ( @{ $value{$value}} ) in perl?

Tags: perl

I have been working for weeks on trying to make a perl program work.  Someone else wrote it and since then the data source has been changed.  I have spent weeks searching line by line and doing tutorials.  I am stuck.  The code says `@{ $Routings{$Code} }` which has a list of values `[ $ProcessID, $Setup, $Process ]` but at the bottom of the code when `foreach ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {my $ProcessCodeID = @$_[0];}` it does not seem to be returning the data.  If anyone could even help me `print $ProcessCodeID` so I can track the data it would be extremely helpful.

Also if you could explain what `@{$value{$key}}` represents that would really help too.

Thanks heaps.

```
%Routings = ();
my $dbh = DBI-> connect('dbi:ODBC:SQL')
    or die "Couldn't open Databaxe: $DBI::errstr;  stopped";

my $query= $dbh->prepare("SELECT Code, Setup, Process, ProcessID FROM ROUTING");

$query->execute() or die "Couldn't execute statement: $DBI::errstr; stopped";

while ( my ($Code, $setup, $process, $processid) = $query->fetchrow_array() ){
    push ( @{ $Routings{$Code} }, [ $ProcessID, $Setup, $Process ] );
}

foreach ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {
    my $ProcessCodeID = @$_[0];
    my $SetupMins = @$_[1];
    my $ProcessMins = @$_[2];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all it is important that you `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, and declare all your variables at the point they are first used. This will cause Perl to generate some very useful messages that will reveal many simple errors that are easily overlooked.

As an example, you are assigning the variables `$setup`, `$process`, and `$processid` but then pushing `$Setup`, `$Process`, and `$ProcessID` onto an array. Perl identifiers are case-sensitive so these are three diffferent variables and will have a value of `undef` at this point. `use strict` would have printed a compilation error saying that `$ProcessID` etc. hadn't been declared. (If you have a choice, it is better to use lower-case plus underscore for local identifiers like these. Seasoned Perl programmers will thank you.)

You should experiment with the [`Data::Dumper` module](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) which will show the contents and structure of a complex nested Perl data structure like this. Once you have `use Data::Dumper` in your program you can write

```
print Dumper \%Routings
```

which will show the contents of `%Routings` as an anonymous hash.

The value of each element `$Routings{$Code}` of the hash is a list (a reference to an array) of all the sets of ProcessID, Setup, and Process that correspond to that value of Code. (I presume the column `Code` is non-unique, otherwise the data structure is more complex than it needs to be.) So the first set of three values for a given `$Code` is at `$Routings{$Code}[0]` and the `ProcessID` for that set is `$Routings{$Code}[0][0]`.

There is no code to assign a value to `$Code` for the `foreach` loop, and presumably you would want to loop over all the keys of the `%Routings` hash.

Each time round the `foreach` loop `$_` is set to a reference to each triplet of values for the current `$Code`. That means `@$_` is a three-element array, but it should be indexed using `$_->[0]` etc. instead of `@$_[0]` which is a one-element *array slice* and poor coding practice. The code is made more obscure by using the default `$_` here and I have clarified it below by using a named variable.

The code below fixes the problems I can see. Please come back if you need any further help.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my %Routings;

my $dbh = DBI-> connect('dbi:ODBC:SQL')
    or die "Couldn't open Databaxe: $DBI::errstr;  stopped";

my $query= $dbh->prepare("SELECT Code, Setup, Process, ProcessID FROM ROUTING");

$query->execute or die "Couldn't execute statement: $DBI::errstr; stopped";

while ( my ($Code, $Setup, $Process, $ProcessID) = $query->fetchrow_array ){
  push @{ $Routings{$Code} }, [ $ProcessID, $Setup, $Process ];
}

for my $Code (keys %Routings) {
  foreach my $triplet ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {
    my $ProcessCodeID = $triplet->[0];
    my $SetupMins = $triplet->[1];
    my $ProcessMins = $triplet->[2];
    print "$Code => ($ProcessCodeID, $SetupMins, $ProcessMins)\n";
  }
}
```

Note that the assignments within the `foreach` loop can be made clearer and more concise by performing them all at once. As I have explained, `@$triplet` is a three-element array, so the equivalent assignment could be coded as simply

```
my ($ProcessCodeID, $SetupMins, $ProcessMins) = @$triplet;
```

(Please treat this code warily, as I cannot test it it thoroughly without significant work setting up a test database, although it does work correctly on a simple data set.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed the difference in the upper and lower case. This now works.  I also appreciate the explanation and help cleaning my code up.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't want to go to the trouble (admittedly very little trouble) of adding `use Data::Dumper` to your code, you can see the same thing by inspecting hashes and arrays using the 'x' command in the perl debugger. Traverse the code until the variable in question is populated, then type `x @{$value{$key}}`. The debugger uses Data::Dumper to display the structure of the array or hash (it actually works better with hash references).

Answer (score 5):

The code is grouping "routing records" by "code".

---

`%Routings` is a hash. It is keyed by "code". Each value is a reference to an array. Those arrays are autovivified by `push ( @{ $Routings{$Code} },`, which is short for `push ( @{ $Routings{$Code} //= [] },`.

Each of those arrays contains a number of "records". Each "record" is a reference to an array of three elements ("process id", "setup" and "process"). They are created by `[ $ProcessID, $Setup, $Process ]`.

A dump would look like:

```
{
   $code0 => [
      [ $ProcessID0, $setup0, $Process0 ],
      [ $ProcessID2, $setup2, $Process2 ],
      ...
   ],
   $code1 => [
      [ $ProcessID1, $setup1, $Process1 ],
      [ $ProcessID5, $setup5, $Process5 ],
      ...
   ],
   $code2 => [
      [ $ProcessID3, $setup3, $Process3 ],
      [ $ProcessID4, $setup4, $Process4 ],
      ...
   ],
   ...
}
```

---

If `$Code` has a meaningful value —you didn't show it getting a value— `$Routings{$code}` would evaluate to one of those array references. From the example above,

```
[
   [ $ProcessID0, $setup0, $Process0 ],
   [ $ProcessID2, $setup2, $Process2 ],
   ...
],
```

`@{ ... }` indicates to Perl that you want to *derefence* that reference. In other words, it tells Perl that you are interested in the array itself.

When you pass an array to foreach, it iterates over its elements. So the first time through the loop, `$_` will hold the following array reference:

```
[ $ProcessID0, $setup0, $Process0 ],
```

The second time,

```
[ $ProcessID2, $setup2, $Process2 ],
```

etc.

`@$_[0]` (short for `@{ $_ }[0]`, which is an incorrectly used `${ $_ }[0]`, which is more readable as `$_->[0]`) gets the first element of the referenced array (`$ProcessID0`). Similarly, `@$_[1]` and `@$_[2]` get `$setup0` and `$Process0`.

---

Of course, then you proceed to do nothing with the data. You probably meant to do

```
foreach ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {
    my $ProcessCodeID = ${$_}[0];
    my $SetupMins     = ${$_}[1];
    my $ProcessMins   = ${$_}[2];
    print("$ProcessCodeID ,$SetupMins, $processMins\n");
}
```

Cleaned up:

```
foreach ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {
    my $ProcessCodeID = $_->[0];
    my $SetupMins     = $_->[1];
    my $ProcessMins   = $_->[2];
    print("$ProcessCodeID, $SetupMins, $processMins\n");
}
```

Cleaned up some more:

```
for ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {
    my ($ProcessCodeID, $SetupMins, $ProcessMins) = @$_;
    print("$ProcessCodeID, $SetupMins, $processMins\n");
}
```

Technically, you could even do

```
for ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {
    print(join(', ', @$_), "\n");
}
```

or

```
print(join(', ', @$_), "\n")
   for @{ $Routings{$Code} };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Your explanation was extremely clear and really helped me understand what I am looking at.

Answer (score 5):

How much do you know of Perl references? You might want to look at a few [tutorials](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html) on [Perl references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

## Quick Reference Tutorial

All three of Perl's basic data structures (scalars, arrays, and hashes) are designed to hold single values of data. For example, I have an array of Employees:

```
$employee_list[0] = "Bob";
$employee_list[1] = "Carol";
$employee_list[2] = "Ted";
$employee_list[3] = "Alice";
```

Yes, there are four pieces of data in my array, but in simple Perl, each item contains only a single value -- a first name. What do I do if I also want the employee's last name, or salary, or job title? There's no simple way of doing that in a basic Perl data structure.

References are a way of allowing you to store more than one piece of data in a Perl variable. Let's look at Bob's complete employee record:

```
$employee{FIRST}  = "Bob";
$employee{LAST}   = "Jones";
$employee{PAY}    = "1400";
$employee{PHONE}  = "1234";
```

Now, how can I squeeze all of that information into `$employee_list[0]`?

Perl allows you to take a *reference* to this hash `%employee` (mainly the location in memory where that hash is stored. You can do this by putting a backslash in front of it:

```
$employee_list[0] = \%employee;
```

Now, in that one `$employee_list[0]` slot, I have a reference to a Perl hash that had all of Bob's employee information. Now, the question is how can I access this information?

I can access the information in my reference by *dereferencing* it. You do that by putting the correct [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29) in front of the reference:

```
$employee_reference = $employee_list[0];
%employee_hash      = %$employee_reference;
print "Employee name is $employee_hash{FIRST} $employee_hash{LAST}\n";
```

I first get the reference, then I can dereference it into a new `%employee_hash`. Once I do that, I can use the information that's in the hash. That's a lot of work. Look at `$employee_reference`. All I'm doing with that is getting the reference, so I can dereference it. Why not cut that step out, and take my dereference right from `$employee_list[0]`?

```
%employee_hash      = %{ $employee_list[0] };
print "Employee name is $employee_hash{FIRST} $employee_hash{LAST}\n";
```

Note I use curly braces around my reference. Curly braces are sort of like parentheses around an equation. They let Perl know what to do first.

Again, though, I'm not really doing anything with `%employee_hash`. It's just a place where I can throw my hash, so I can print it. Why not dereference the hash, and get the value of a particular key in one step?
Even better. In a single step:

```
print "Employee name is "
   . ${ $employee_list[0] }{FIRST} . " "
   . ${ $employee_list[0] }{LAST} . "\n";
```

I am dereferencing `$employee_list[0]` into a hash ***and*** taking that hash, and retrieving the value of a particular key all in the same step. Note that I use a `$` instead of a `%`.

As you can see, it can get complicated fast. However, Perl gives you a nice way to represent this overly complex structure:

```
print "Employee name is " 
  . $employee_list[0]->{FIRST} . " " 
  . $employee_list[0]->{LAST} . "\n";
```

The `->` operator takes the *dereference* for you.

It's also sort of silly of me building a hash called `%employee_hash` just to take a reference of it. Perl allows you to refer to *anonymous* hashes and arrays.

```
$employee_list[0] = { LAST => "Jones", FIRST => "Bob",
    SALARY => 1400, PHONE => "1234" }
```

The curly braces are for *anonymous* hashes. Square brackets are for *anonymous* arrays. They're anonymous because they don't refer to a variable, but are simply a reference to a hash or array.

## Data::Dumper

As you can imagine, these data structures can get quite complex. For example, I keep track of the employee's address, but an address consists of a street, city, state, and zip. Sometimes, there's more than one line for the street. And, what if there's more than one address? There's no reason why a hash or array reference can't contain a reference to another hash or array:

```
$employee_list[0]->{NAME}->{FIRST} = "Bob";
$employee_list[0]->{NAME}->{LAST}  = "Jones";
$employee_list[0]->{ADDRESS}->[0]->{TYPE} = "Business";
$employee_list[0]->{ADDRESS}->[0]->{STREET}->[0] = "123 Mockingbird Lane";
$employee_list[0]->{ADDRESS}->[0]->{STREET}->[1] = "Tower 2";
$employee_list[0]->{ADDRESS}->[0]->{CITY} = "Beantown";
$employee_list[0]->{ADDRESS}->[0]->{STATE} = "MA";
```

As you can see $employee_list[0] points to a reference to an employee hash. That hash has a "NAME", "ADDRESS", and other keys filled with data. The `NAME` field is a reference to another hash that has two keys: `FIRST` and `LAST`. The `ADDRESS` field is actually a reference to an array of addresses. And each of those array entries is a reference to a hash. Imagine trying to debug this data structure!

[Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is a module that will parse through the most complex data structures and print them out for you:

```
use Data::Dumper;

[...]

print "Employee Dump: " . Dumper \@employee . "\n";
```

That will print out the entire structure of all the employees in the employee array.

If you don't know what `@{$value{$key}}` is, you could easily run a dump on it:

```
print Dumper $value{$key} . "\n";
```

## Decoding Your Program

Let's go through the lines one by one:

```
%Routings = ();
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:SQL')
    or die "Couldn't open Databaxe: $DBI::errstr;  stopped";
```

You initialized a hash called `%Routings` and created a DBI object that represents a connection to your database. `connect` is a subroutine that's defined in Perl as part of the DBI class. All classes consist of a bunch of Perl subroutines that operate on objects created by that class. These subroutines are divided into *constructors* and *methods*. Constructors create a reference to a complex data structure that represents the object. Methods are subroutines that can operate on that object. Imagine our employee record:

```
$employee = Person::Employee->new;
$employee->first_name( "Bob" );
```

The first line creates an `$employee` object from my `Person::Employee` class. That `$employee` object is really just a reference to a hash that contains my employee information. So, my subroutine `new` is a *constructor*.

The second line uses a subroutine called `first_name` that allows me to set the first name of the employee. This subroutine is called a *Method* or sometimes a *Member Function*.

So, getting back to the program, we created an object that represents our database connection. If you want, you can use `Data::Dumper` to print out the structure of this *object* if that helps you understand it a bit better. It's just a reference to a hash.

```
my $query= $dbh->prepare("SELECT Code, Setup, Process, ProcessID FROM ROUTING");
$query->execute() or die "Couldn't execute statement: $DBI::errstr; stopped";
```

I now *prepare* my SQL statement that I want to execute. After I prepare it, I execute it. The execution is really what hits the database. Notice that my `prepare` is a *method* for the database handle `$dbi`, but it's also a constructor because it created the `$query` object.

I use that `$query` object to actually execute my query. Again, don't be afraid of using `Data::Dumper` to print it out.

```
while ( my ($Code, $setup, $process, $processid) = $query->fetchrow_array() ){
    push ( @{ $Routings{$Code} }, [ $ProcessID, $Setup, $Process ] );
}
```

Let's simplify this a bit:

```
while ( my @fetched_row = $query->fetchrow_array() ){
    my ($Code, $setup, $process, $processid) = @fetched_row;
    push ( @{ $Routings{$Code} }, [ $ProcessID, $Setup, $Process ] );
}
```

The `fetchrow_array` is a subroutine that fetches one row from my query as an array of columns. This subroutine is a *method* of the `$query` object I created above. All I'm doing is fetching each row from my database and putting it into four Perl scalar variables.

The last line is a bit tricky. Remember my `%Routings` hash I initialized? Apparently, each key in this hash is a reference to an array of values. The hash is keyed upon `$Code` which I fetched above, and this points to a three-member array made up of `$ProcesssID`, `$Setup`, and `$Process`. We could rewrite the third line like this:

```
my @temp_array = ($ProcessID, $Setup, $Process);
my @temp_routing_array = @{ $Routings{Code} }; #Dereferencing the $Routing{$Code} array
push( @temp_routing_array, \@temp_array );     #Pushing a reference into my array
$Routing{$Code} = \@temp_routing_array;   #Creating a reference again
```

The `[ $ProcessID, $Setup, $Process ]` is merely creating a reference to an anonymous array. This saves us the trouble of creating `@temp_array` and then pushing the reference of `@temp_array` into my `@temp_routing_array`.

And, while we're at it, **there's an error in your code**. I am fetching `$setup`, `$process`, and `$processid`, but I am storing (watch the casing of the variable names) `$Setup`, `$Process`, and `$ProcessID`.

Now, we're getting to the foreach loop **and another bug**. What's the value of `$Code`? It has no value because the variable `$Code` only exists in the `while` loop above. When you declare a variable with `my`, the value of this variable is lost once you leave a block of code.

This error, and the one above could have been caught if you had [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of your program.

Let's look at this loop:

```
foreach ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {
    my $ProcessCodeID = @$_[0];
    my $SetupMins = @$_[1];
    my $ProcessMins = @$_[2];
}
```

This `foreach` loop is using an obsolete style where you assume you are looping through the `$_` variable. It's confusing and most people have learned not to use it. Let's rewrite it:

```
my @routing_code_ref_array = @{ $Routings{$Code} };

foreach my $routing_array_ref (@routing_code_ref_array) {
    my @routing_array = @{ $routing_array_ref };

    my $ProcessCodeID  = $routing_array[0];
    my $SetupMins      = $routing_array[1];
    my $ProcessMins    = $routing_array[2];
}
```

Remember that `$Routings{$Code}` is a reference to an array. In my first line, I'm dereferencing it. In the original code, the dereferencing took place in the `foreach` loop. Not only was `$Routings{$Code}` an array reference, but each entry in that array was a reference to another array. It is an [array of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

So, each entry in my `@routing_code_ref_array` is a reference to another array which I dereference once again. Now I'm just taking the values of each array element and putting it into regular Perl scalar variables.

## Enough Already!

Sorry for the long explanation, but you had some code that touched on references, classes, methods, constructors, objects, and a whole bunch of rather advanced Perl topics. As well as a few errors that I pointed out. Errors that could have been caught with a couple of standard Perl pragmas: `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

If there is anything you can take away it is:

- Things like `@$foo{$bar}[4]` or `@{ $foo{bar} }[4]` or (more correctly) `${ $foo{bar} }[4]` or (more clearly) `$foo{bar}->[4]` are references to more complex data structures. The basic Perl data structures can only hold a single item at a time. By using references to other data structures, you can have arrays of arrays or arrays of hashes or hashes of hashes or hashes of arrays, or even arrays of hashes of hashes of arrays of hashes. Don't panic and try to parse these things out from the inside out. Sometimes it's easier if you can handle a particularly complex data structure in multiple lines.
- If you're going to run into complex structures, `Data::Dumper` is your friend. It will quickly reveal the structure of these overly complex structures and can help you debug issues with your program.
- Use `strict` and `warnings` in your programs. These will pick up a lot of programming goofs. As I said, I found two related to both the scope of a local variable, and mistyping in the case of variable names. It is also a grand idea to standardize variable names. The two methods are camelCasing and using only underscores and lowercase letters. This way, you know it's always `$foo_bar` and never `$Foo_Bar` or `$FooBar` or `$fooBar`. The old standard was camel casing with the first letter being a lowercase letter. The new standard is using lowercase letters and underscores only.

Comment: It is incorrect and misleading to say *"This foreach loop is using an obsolete style where you assume you are looping through the $_ variable. It's confusing and most people have learned not to use it."*. There is a place for both named and default loop control variables, and the latter is most certainly not obsolete.

Comment: @Borodin Damian Conway _Perl Best Practices_, covers the use of `$_` in the section on _Iterator Variables_ in Chapter 6. He mainly covers the maintainability issues. However, there's also a problem of _spooky action at a distance_. You have a `for` loop, and as part of the `for` loop, you call a subroutine that also uses `$_`. Since `$_` is global, it will get changed on you. Non-esplicit use of these _Mysterious Moe_ global variables don't improve readability, confuse new comers, and are maintenance headaches.

Comment: I know what PBP says and agree that there can be problems using `$_` with anything more than ordinary loops, but it is equivalent to using pronouns in spoken language which has exactly the same problems. I don't hear anyone calling for the abolition of the word *it*, and simply taking care not to be ambiguous is sufficient. It is far from being a *obsolete style* and by no means have *most people* learned not to use it. It is even mandatory when using `map` or `grep`.

Comment: The default use of the `$_` variable in commands and loops can cause maintenance headaches, is no more efficient than explicitly using a `my` variable, and is more likely to obfuscate code than to clarify it. In a very simple `for` loop `$_` might not hurt readability, but `$_` rarely improves readability. Ask yourself this: Did the use of `$_` make the `foreach` statement on top any more readable -- especially since the developer had to use `$_` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually *trying* to `return` the data -- it is simply creating variables with the data and then promptly doing nothing with the data. Try this:

```
foreach ( @{ $Routings{$Code} } ) {
    my $ProcessCodeID = @$_[0];
    my $SetupMins = @$_[1];
    my $ProcessMins = @$_[2];
    print "$Code: $ProcessCodeID, $SetupMins, $ProcessMins\n";
}
```

Unless you use the variables within the loop, there's not much point having it.

The complicated-ish `@{ $foo{$bar} }` construct is telling Perl to treat `$foo{$bar}` as an array. `$foo{$bar}` is a hash lookup. (See the `%Routings = ();` at the top? That declares and initializes the hash.)

Perl is definitely neat but things like this were enough to make me decide to write new code in newer languages such as Ruby. This code might not be significantly nicer in Ruby, either, and someone well-versed in either wouldn't really care, but you might wish to take the opportunity to re-write tools as you need them maintained.

Comment: Hi @sarnold,  Thanks for the prompt reply.  I tried the print line and it did not return anything. No new errors, but no print/data either.

Comment: Actually, Perl knows exactly what it's in `$Routings{$Code}`. Then syntax of `foreach (@{$Routings{$Code}})` is not `foreach ($Routings{$Code})` because `foreach ($Routings{$Code})` does something too.

Comment: @ikegami: many thanks for Perl-izing my answer _and_ the correction. Both are appreciated!